# Why Is My Volume Emission So Blocky?

Tags: volumetrics

Can someone explain to me what is happening here and how to get around it?  I have a volume object (cloud) that I want to give a soft glow.  However the glow is very blocky, yet the mesh that the volume is based on is not.  And the voxel size is smaller than the blockiness.

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2x21zmvr4muauy8/Emission%20Blockiness.blend?dl=0)

This is the object without emission:
[image]

With emission:
[image]